# How to set Apache header only if environment variable has a certain value

Tags: apache, http-headers, apache2, apache2.4, mod-headers

I want to set a header in my Apache (2.4) config, but only if an environment variable has a certain value.

```
SetEnv ENV_NAME prod
```

How do I only set this header if `ENV_NAME` is not `prod` ?

```
Header set X-Robots-Tag "noindex, nofollow"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Header set X-Robots-Tag "noindex, nofollow" "expr=env('ENV_NAME') != 'prod'"
```

From https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_headers.html#header

> The Header directive may be followed by an additional argument, which
> may be any of:
>
> ...
>
> `expr=expression` The directive is applied if and only if expression
> evaluates to true. Details of expression syntax and evaluation are
> documented in the [ap_expr](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/expr.html) documentation.