# htaccess HSTS prevents redirection from www.subdomain.domain.com to subdomain.domain.com

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, subdomain, hsts

I have a website where the user can make unlimited subdomains for that website.
One of our customers wants us to have HSTS enabled on the header so I added the following rule to my .htaccess:

```
Header set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains"
```

We have a wildcard certificate `*.domain.com` to secure all the subdomains, because we don't want to make for every subdomain a seperate certificate.

The problem is when someone is going to `www.subdomain.domain.com` they need to be redirected to `subdomain.domain.com`.
But Chrome is blocking the redirect because there is no valid certificate on a `*.*.domain.com` level and the HSTS rules makes Chrome block the redirect completely with a `NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID` error.

Part of the .htaccess that matters:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,QSA,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,QSA,R=301,L]

Header set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains"
Header always set Cache-Control "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate"
```

I was expecting that the www to non-www redirect would go first because it is higher in the .htaccess file.

Comment: `mod_rewrite` and `mod_headers` are different modules, so the rules governing which mod_rewrite rules are executed do not necessarily apply to other modules. I think your best bet is to set an environment variable with mod_rewrite based on the domain, and only set HSTS if that environment variable is set. Something like : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62559797/how-to-set-apache-header-only-if-environment-variable-has-a-certain-value

Comment: @Sumurai8 I think that the biggest problem is that once people visited sub.domain.com the HSTS is set, which is good, but then also www.sub.domain.com has the HSTS now enabled. And I can't remove includeSubdomains because the .htaccess is sharedd for domain.com and for sub.domain.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to enable HSTS on the www sub-subdomain, you need to put an `<If>` statement around the header and not use `includeSubDomains` in your HSTS rule.

Without `<If "%{HTTP_HOST} != 'www.sub.example.com'>` around the `Header` directive for HSTS, that header will be sent for that subdomain, regardless of the order of the rules in your .htaccess file.

When you use `includeSubDomains` in your HSTS rule, HSTS for `www.sub.example.com` will be enabled when you visit `sub.example.com` or even `example.com`.

Now that you have enabled HSTS for that www subdomain, there is **no way for you to revoke** it for browsers that have already visited your site.  At this point, your best course of action is to get a certificate that covers the www subdomain.  You can probably add at to your existing certificate as a Subject Alternative Name (SAN).

Comment: There are a lot of subdomains and every day there can be more/less so adding them would cost a lot time. I tested above out and I don't think it will help me because sub.example.com needs to have HSTS, and when I dont include includeSubdomain those subdomains dont have HSTS anymore active. Simple said I want a redirect from www to non-www above everything else,

Comment: I noticed that in Plesk http to https redirect was on, so I removed that. When I visited `http://www.sub.domain.com` I get redirected to `https://sub.domain.com` with the website visible. But when I visit `http://www.sub.domain.com` again I redirects me to `https://www.sub.domain.com` and I get the HTST error

Comment: That is because HSTS requires that redirects from `http` do nothing except change `http` to `https`.     After you get the HSTS rule, the redirect will be forever ignored and HSTS will handle changing to https for you even without the redirect.

Comment: Maybe you should enable HSTS just on this one subdomain and get the certificate for its `www.` sub-subdomain and not try to do this for other customers.   HSTS is a nice idea, but it has some really annoying implications when sub-subdomains are involved. (or when you want to use private subdomains on your intranet.)

Comment: Thats sounds like actualy a good plan, so that means that I change the if statement to the sub2.domain.com, and register only that www certificate?

Comment: That sounds reasonable to me.   You may end up with a few people that got the HSTS rule for your whole site who will continue to have problems with other sub-subdomains, but hopefully not too many.

Comment: So I removed the whole HSTS part out of the htaccess and inside Plesk I made a seperate subdomain hosting and activated HSTS there  including the IncludeSubdomain together with a www certificate as well. And now everything works good for that subdomain. I could also override the head.php file for every sbudomain if I want by creating it in a seperate directory named as the subdomain, so I could also added the HSTS rule there as a header() tag. But everything configured inside Plesk seems like a good idea. Thanks for helping out :)

Comment: ... And you don't have problems when you visit sub1.domain.com bcs the HSTS rule only applies to sub2.domain.com thanks to the seperate hosting directive inside Plesk

Answer (score 0):

> ...and the HSTS rules makes Chrome block the redirect completely with a `NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID` error

That's nothing to do with HSTS. That error is "because there is no valid certificate on a `*.*.domain.com` level". You would have had the same error before trying to implement HSTS. (Unless you only ever tested the www sub-subdomain over HTTP only?!)

There is no shortcut. If you need the www sub-subdomain to be accessible over HTTPS then you need a valid security cert that covers that hostname.

> I was expecting that the www to non-www redirect would go first because it is higher in the .htaccess file.

The `NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID` is a *browser* error that occurs during the SSL handshake. This all happens *before* `.htaccess` is even processed (before any data is transmitted).

---

*Aside:* Although do you really need a www sub-subdomain?

Comment: It kinda does have something to do with HSTS because once a browser gets the HSTS rule it will never hit the HTTP site to see the redirect and will always try to redirect using HTTPS.  Without HSTS, type in traffic with the www would get redirected using HTTP, but now with HSTS, type in traffic goes straight to HTTPS.

Comment: As for really needing the www sub-subdomain, a large number of people add www to anything.     You really do need it.   I had some subdomains without the www sub-subdomain and got numerous complaints that the site was not accessible until I enabled it.

Comment: yes same here, the customers are typing www anyways. HSTS has to something with it because HSTS makes you not be able to allow the invalid certificate. Normaly when HSTS is not enabled you would get a button that you can continue anyways, which is ofcourse also bad practise. And the HTSTS is indeed making the customer first go to HTTPS which I don't want.

Comment: I noticed that in Plesk http to https redirect was on, so I removed that. When I visited `http://www.sub.domain.com` I get redirected to `https://sub.domain.com` with the website visible. But when I visit `http://www.sub.domain.com` again I redirects me to `https://www.sub.domain.com` and I get the HTST error